# AutoHotKey: InputBox with multiline input

Tags: windows, user-interface, autohotkey

In AutoHotKey, I want to have something like InputBox except that the text input is multiline. (i.e. like a textarea).

I want there to be two buttons, "Ok" and "Cancel", and I want them both to have accelerators. I want this code to be in the form of a function that I can call from other hotkeys to get multiline user input whenever I want. I want to be able to set the default text shown when the dialog is shown. I want the function to return null or empty string if the cancel button was pressed. I want the Esc key to cause the dialog to be closed as if the cancel button was pressed (and not exit the entire script). I want the dialog to show in the center of the screen, and to use the font that Windows usually uses for dialogs.

Comment: You seem to know what you *want*. Where do you have difficulties implementing it?

Comment: I don't know how to deal with the `gui` command.

Comment: The [Gui docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Gui.htm) have a very comprehensive explanation of possible parameters and many examples. This should get you started.

Comment: For the textbox, you are looking for `Gui, Add, Edit, R20 vMyEdit
` - check out the full example in the AHK help file that came with your installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
!1::
MsgBox % MultiLineInputBox("Hello World:", "stuff, more stuff", "Custom Caption")
return

MultiLineInputBox(Text:="", Default:="", Caption:="Multi Line Input Box"){
    static
    ButtonOK:=ButtonCancel:= false
    if !MultiLineInputBoxGui{
        Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Text, r1 w600  , % Text
        Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Edit, r10 w600 vMultiLineInputBox, % Default
        Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Button, w60 gMultiLineInputBoxOK , &OK
        Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Button, w60 x+10 gMultiLineInputBoxCancel, &Cancel
        MultiLineInputBoxGui := true
    }
    GuiControl,MultiLineInputBox:, MultiLineInputBox, % Default
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox: Show,, % Caption
    SendMessage, 0xB1, 0, -1, Edit1, A
    while !(ButtonOK||ButtonCancel)
        continue
    if ButtonCancel
        return
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox: Submit, NoHide
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox: Cancel
    return MultiLineInputBox
    ;----------------------
    MultiLineInputBoxOK:
    ButtonOK:= true
    return
    ;---------------------- 
    MultiLineInputBoxGuiEscape:
    MultiLineInputBoxCancel:
    ButtonCancel:= true
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox: Cancel
    return
}
```

Comment: **Potential bug**: Once a MultiLineInputBox has been created, the prompt text for all subsequent input boxes cannot be changed. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Tvf.png))

Comment: @ThierryDalon The behavior may have changed in newer versions of AutoHotkey. Unfortunately, I don't remember which version I was using when I saw the bug.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: now I have this bug too!

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: I think I've come to a fix of this bug. See my separate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300246/2043349

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it pretty short:
(tested and works)

```
MultiLineInput(Text:="Waiting for Input") {
    Global MLI_Edit
    Gui, Add, Edit, vMLI_Edit x2 y2 w396 r4
    Gui, Add, Button, gMLI_OK x1 y63 w199 h30, &OK
    Gui, Add, Button, gMLI_Cancel x200 y63 w199 h30, &Cancel
    Gui, Show, h94 w400, %Text%
    Goto, MLI_Wait
    MLI_OK:
        GuiControlGet, MLI_Edit
    MLI_Cancel:
    GuiEscape:
        ReturnNow := True
    MLI_Wait:
        While (!ReturnNow)
            Sleep, 100
    Gui, Destroy
    Return %MLI_Edit%
}

MsgBox % MultiLineInput("Tell me 5 things you like.")
```

This is what it could look like:
[image]

And here is what it returns printed in a MsgBox: [Click](http://i.snag.gy/5uRBs.jpg)

Comment: I recommend renaming the parameter `Text` to `Title`. It matches the parameter name used by InputBox and describes the intended use a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Updated version from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25800045/2043349 that fixes the bug that the Prompt Text won't be updated if you use the function multiple times:

```
MultiLineInputBox(Text:="", Default:="", Caption:="Multi Line Input Box")
{
    static
    ButtonOK:=ButtonCancel:= false
    Gui GuiMLIB:New,, % Caption
    Gui, add, Text, w600, % Text
    Gui, add, Edit, r10 w600 vMLIBEdit, % Default
    Gui, add, Button, w60 gMLIBOK , &OK
    Gui, add, Button, w60 x+10 gMLIBCancel, &Cancel

    Gui, Show
    while !(ButtonOK||ButtonCancel)
        continue
    if ButtonCancel
        return
    Gui, Submit
    return MLIBEdit
    ;----------------------
    MLIBOK:
    ButtonOK:= true
    return
    ;---------------------- 
    GuiMLIBGuiEscape:
    GuiMLIBGuiClose:
    MLIBCancel:
    ButtonCancel:= true
    Gui, Cancel
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code:

**Version 1 (with Gosub):**

```
return
StartGui:
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y19 w240 h120 vMyEdit, Here is default text
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y179 w100 h30 gGuiCloseOk, Ok
Gui, Add, Button, x162 y179 w100 h30 gGuiCloseCancel, Cancel
; Generated using SmartGUI Creator for SciTE
Gui, Show, w286 h231, My Gui Name

WinGetPos,,, Width, Height, My Gui Name
WinMove, My Gui Name,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(Width/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)

return

return
GuiCloseOK:
GuiControlGet, MyEdit
Gui, Destroy
return

GuiCloseCancel:
MyEdit:=""
Gui, Destroy
return


return
Esc::
Gui, Destroy
return
```

Place that code in your script anywhere you like. To call for the GUI add anywhere you want `Gosub, StartGui`. The content of *Edit* control you will get in `MyEdit` variable.

For example, if you want to call GUI by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> put that code in  script anywhere you want:

```
return
!^z::
    Gosub, StartGui
return
```

**Version 2 (with function):**

```
GuiFunc(DefaultText)
{
    global MyEdit
    MyEdit:=""
    Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y19 w240 h120 vMyEdit, %DefaultText%
    Gui, Add, Button, x22 y179 w100 h30 gGuiCloseOk, &Ok
    Gui, Add, Button, x162 y179 w100 h30 gGuiCloseCancel, &Cancel
    ; Generated using SmartGUI Creator for SciTE
    Gui, Show, w286 h231, My Gui Name

    WinGetPos,,, Width, Height, My Gui Name
    WinMove, My Gui Name,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(Width/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)

    return

    return
    GuiCloseOK:
    GuiControlGet, MyEdit
    Gui, Destroy
    return

    GuiCloseCancel:
    MyEdit:=""
    Gui, Destroy
    return

}


return
Esc::
    Gui, Destroy
return
```

Place that code in your script anywhere you like. To call for the GUI, call `GuiFunc(DefaultText)` function with parameter that is text to display in *Edit* control by default. After running function global variable `MyEdit` is set to the content of *Edit* control. So you can use `MyEdit` variable anywhere outside the function. I know that you wanted function to return content of `MyEdit` variable but I tried it many ways with no success.

For example, put that code in your script anywhere you want. To call GUI press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and to display content of `MyEdit` variable press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> :

```
return
!^z::
    DefaultText:= "Here is default text"
    GuiFunc(DefaultText)
return

return
!^a::
    MsgBox, %MyEdit%
return
```

For both versions, if you decide to rename Window Title `My Gui Name` then keep in mind that you need to rename it in 3 places for script to work properly.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: A few issues: 1. Do you mind providing it in a function rather than a subroutine? I'm more comfortable with that. I'd expect it to be a function that takes the prompt text and the placeholder text to put in the text input, and return the text the user put if he pressed okay or some null value if he pressed cancel or esc. 2. Accelerators are letters in the button text that are underlined, so if you press alt and that letter the button is invoked. 3. Do you mind indenting the code? It would be easier to read and understand.

Comment: @RamRachum Version 2 added. As far as I understand there is what you need except that function does not returns anything. After running function global variable `MyEdit` is set to the content of *Edit* control. Please check it.

Comment: @RamRachum I have improved version 2. Now you can call function without  `global MyEdit` and `MyEdit:=""` before calling function. They are moved inside function.

Comment: So many explanations... Instead of simply a function that returns a value, like we've been using for decades in the software development world. Why?

Comment: @RamRachum From your profile I see that you are professional programmer but not everyone else are. Not everything that is easy for you is also easy for others. For example, programming for me is only hobby and I don't have special education in programming and when I ask questions about programming I personally prefer when everything is explained, its easy for me to understand that way. Also many other people who are using AutoHotkey are not professional programmers and some of them will read that answer and maybe they will find something useful for them.

Comment: There's lots of things in software development and in life that I'm a novice in. Being inexperienced is no shame. But I'd prefer to get *answers* only from experienced people. In the same way I wouldn't try to answer in a field where I'm a novice in, I'd let other people answer and maybe learn from them.

Comment: @RamRachum You have a very strange reaction when someone is trying to help you. Stackoverflow and other stackexchange websites are not only for experts. There are many people that are not experts and are actually helping each other and there is no rule that states that only experts should answer. If you need only expert answer next time you can write in your question:  **Please answer if you are only expert. All others are not welcomed!**. But in that case I don't think anyone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [alpha bravo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25800045/3503851) and [Thierry Dalon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300246/3503851).

- This is fixing the problem of either always having `ErrorLevel=1` even when
  the user clicks `Ok button` or not having `ErrorLevel=1` when user clicks the `cancel button` or exits/interrupts the input box.
- Also  it uses `WinWaitClose` instead of `while loop` that seems better for me.
- Removes unneeded lines having `GuiControl` and `SendMessage`.

```
MultiLineInputBox(Text:="", Defualt:="", Caption:="Multi Line Input Box"){
  static
  ; futher helper variables
    local is_interrupted := ""     ; helper variable to know if submitted/interrupted       [tn1]
  Gui MultiLineInputBox:New,, % Caption
  Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Text, r1 w600  , % Text
  Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Edit, r10 w600 vMultiLineInputBoxContent, % DefaultText
  Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Button, w60 gMultiLineInputBoxOK , &OK
  Gui, MultiLineInputBox: add, Button, w60 x+10 gMultiLineInputBoxCancel, &Cancel
  
  Gui, MultiLineInputBox: Show
  Gui, MultiLineInputBox:+HwndMultiLineInputBox_hwnd
  WinWaitClose, ahk_id %MultiLineInputBox_hwnd%
  if (is_interrupted) {
    ErrorLevel := 1
  }
  return MultiLineInputBoxContent
  ;----------------------
  MultiLineInputBoxOK:
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox:Submit
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox:Destroy
  return
  ;---------------------- 
  MultiLineInputBoxCancel:
  MultiLineInputBoxClose:
  MultiLineInputBoxGuiEscape:
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox: Cancel
    Gui, MultiLineInputBox:Destroy
    is_interrupted := True
  return
}
```